# passing url from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, url, servlets, parameters

I have the following JSP code:

```
<%
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
Entry var = (Entry) list.get(i);
//[...]
String Cn = var.getCn();
out.println(" <form method=\"get\" action=\"NewServlet\"> "+ "<input \
    type=\"submit\" name=\"act\" value=\" " + var.getCn() + " \" > " + "</form>");
out.println("<br>--------------------<br>");
}
%>
```

I want to send the parameter `var.getCn()` to the servlet, but I don't know how to catch it from the servlet. How can I do this?

```
//[....]
   String Cn = new String();
   Cn = request.getParameter("???");                
//[....]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
    String bar = request.getParameter("bar");
    // Do something with foo & bar.

}
```

URL:

```
http://example.com/myservlet/?foo="hey"&bar="funny"
```

Read [more](http://www.users.csbsju.edu/~lziegler/CS317/NetProgramming/ParameterToServlet.html).